# How can I use VBA to format Symbols / Icons into cells without using conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, symbols, conditional-formatting, performance

I am using VBA code to place  conditional formatting to cover values in a large table, I use 2 formulae per cell to determine which of the 3 symbols to use.  I need to check the value of each cell with a different cell depending on the column and therefore as far as I understamd, I have to place my conditional formatting rule on each cell individually to ensure the formula is correct in each.  This is because conditional formatting cannot take relative addresses, you have to give it the exact address of each cell ... correct?

The large number of conditional formatting instances is slowing my computer to a huge extent.

Is it possible to place symbols used by conditional formatting, into a cell, without using conditional formatting?

Perhaps somewhat like an image, but whilst retaining the cell value underneath, as can be done using conditional formatting.

Below I have given the code I use to put the conditional formatting in place. Any help is very much appreciated!!

```
    Dim AIs As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range

    Set AIs = ActiveSheet.Range("Table")
    For Each cl In AIs.Columns
        For Each rng In cl.Cells

        rng.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
        rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With rng.FormatConditions(1)
            .ReverseOrder = False
            .ShowIconOnly = True
            .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Symbols2)
        End With

         With rng.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(1)
            .Icon = xlIconYellowExclamationSymbol
        End With
        With rng.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(2)
            .Icon = xlIconRedCross

            .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
            .Value = "=IF(VALUE(LEFT(" & rng.Parent.Cells(5, rng.Column).Address & _
                  ";1)=0;1;6)"

            .Operator = 7
        End With
        With rng.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(3)
            .Icon = xlIconGreenCheck

            .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
            .Value = "=IF(VALUE(LEFT(" & rng.Address & ";1))<=VALUE(LEFT(" & _
                  rng.Parent.Cells(5, rng.Column).Address & ";1));1;6)"

            .Operator = 7
        End With
        Next rng
    Next cl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a shape directly to a cell:

```
Dim cLeft As Single
Dim cTop As Single

cLeft = rng.Left
cTop = rng.Top

with AIs.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, cLeft, cTop, 12, 12)
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    'Other properties can be found at
    'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb251480%28v=office.12%29.aspx
end with
```

you may want to adjust cTop and cLeft, and the width/height to position the circle as you wish

Comment: error 1004 object failure, I have attempted to manually put in relative addresses into conditional formatting formulas and I always get the same message telling me conditional formatting can only accept absalute addresses.  I believe this error 1004 is arising because I am telling the VBA code to put a relative address into a conditional formatting formula which is then spitting back this error.

The end result is to put an icon into the cell as seen in the code `code .icon = xlIconGreenCheck `etc.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Perhaps it a unique condition for the symbolize operations in conditional formatting, that I can't put relative addresses in.

Do you know of any other reason why that wouldn't work, or have you used relative addresses in formulae for symbolized conditional formatting before?

Comment: for symbolized formula, relative is not an option (thanks, excel). It may be better to have a 'helper' column that has the reults of the formula, then assign the icons based on the cell (e.g., below 1, red, equal to 1, amber, above 1, green (or however you want the icons to appear), and use the option to hide the underlying value in the cell (`.ShowIconOnly = True`)

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, as in have a hidden column beside each of my columns to house the result of the formula and then ask conditional formatting to look at this value.  The only problem is that that also requires that I put a seperate conditional formatting rule into each cell in order to house a formula saying look at "this other cell" And that leaves me with the same problem of having ~10000 instances of conditional formatting rules on each worksheet.  :)  Thanks for the uick reply, but I don't see it working.

Comment: You're not aware of any way I can grab the symbols I want and put them into a cell using VBA directly are you?  That way I would perform the conditional checks in VBA and then just permanently write the symbols to the cells. The worksheet wn't be altered and upon moving between sheets old ones are deleted and refreshed so VBA can do any and all updating that might be necessary

Comment: re-wrote answer to add a shape to a cell, rather than use conditional formatting

Comment: Thanks @Sean Cheshire,  I tried that solution.  Unfortunately the forms are not placed into the restraints of the cells but rather positioned over them using their coordinates on the sheet.  This means that they can be moved accidentally, they are not subject to alterations in the cell size or are not hidden when the céll is hidden.  Truly thank you for your help with this, you've given me some other ideas which I will try and I'll post up a solution when I get one. :)

Comment: `.Placement = xlMoveAndSize` keeps a shape with the cell, and will hide/move as the cell does the same

Comment: Thank you so much @Sean Cheshire it wasn't actually the `.Placement` that I needed´, it was `ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True`  The `.Placement`didn't really work well as the rows or columns I had hidden or some which I reduce to be so small that only the border is visible, ended up having the shapes stuck either half way between the cells or in the next cell. so it was easier to remove the shapes on every action and then reinstate them only on visible cells using some if statements :)

Answer (score 0):

Final code:

```
     Set AIs = ActiveSheet.Range("Table")
     For Each cl In AIs.Columns
        For Each rng In cl.Cells

            'Shapes  - GRADE MASK


            cLeft = rng.Left + 5 - (rng.ColumnWidth / 2)
            cTop = rng.Top + (rng.RowHeight / 2 - 5)

            If Not rng = "" And rng.ColumnWidth = 3 And rng.RowHeight > 12 Then

            If rng.Parent.Cells(5, rng.Column) = 0 Then
                With wks.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, cLeft, cTop, 10, 10)
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End With
            End If
            If CInt(Left(rng, 1)) >= CInt(Left(rng.Parent.Cells(5, rng.Column), 1)) And _
             Not rng.Parent.Cells(5, rng.Column) = 0 Then
                With wks.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, cLeft, cTop, 10, 10)
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                End With
            End If
            If CInt(Left(rng, 1)) < CInt(Left(rng.Parent.Cells(5, rng.Column), 1)) Then
                With wks.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, cLeft, cTop, 10, 10)
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 204, 0)
                End With
            End If
            End If
        Next rng
    Next cl

    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, _
       userinterfaceonly:=True
```

Then every time I call a macro, I remove all the shapes on the worksheet, perform my macro and then call this again, in the if statements above there are checks to see how big the column width and row height are and a shape is only inserted if the cell is "visible"

In my program, for other reasons outside this subroutine I cannot hide my rows or columns but instead reduce their height or width to be just big enough to display the cell borders.